# Transform an SQL query in Joomla Jdatabase syntax query?

Tags: sql, joomla

I know a bit SQL but not at all Jdatabase.

I would like to write this query:
'SELECT deal_id, name FROM products,cities WHERE products.location_id = cities.id'

in Jdatabase syntax.

It should looks like bit:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->select(array('name', 'name')) 
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__products','#__cities')) 
   ->where($db->quoteName.....?????????
$db->setQuery($query); 
$row = $db->loadRow();
```

Then after that, I would like to load the result of this query in an array and display one specific value.

I explain: this array would be to display a list of products. Irt will be done by php loop, and on each product , I want to display the city of product by using the array and product_id.

Someone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Format it Just Like a Sql-Command:

```
 $query->select(array('#__products.name', '#__cities.name')) 
       ->from($db->quoteName(array('#__products','#__cities'))) 
       ->where($db->quoteName('#__cities.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('#__products.location_id'))
```

BUT:::
Consider using an Left JOIN.

```
 $query->select(array('#__products.name', '#__cities.name')) 
       ->from($db->quoteName('#__products'))
       ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__cities') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('#__cities.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('#__products.location_id') . ')')
```